# Google Diff Bar Chart - Change Bar Color

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Google Diff Bar chart. I am trying to change the color of the exterior bar. By default it is a faded color. I am able to change the inner bar color with color parameter under options. Can someone guide me out please? Here is my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", '1.1', {packages:['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var oldData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Name', 'Popularity'],
  ['Cesar', 250],
  ['Rachel', 4200],
  ['Patrick', 2900],
  ['Eric', 8200]
]);

var newData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Name', 'Popularity'],
  ['Cesar', 370],
  ['Rachel', 600],
  ['Patrick', 700],
  ['Eric', 3500]
]);
var colChartDiff = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('colchart_diff'));
var options = { 
diff: { newData: { widthFactor: 0.6 } },
legend: { position: 'top' } ,
colors: ['#f38eff', '#C0C0C0'],
backgroundColor: '#fffff5',
hAxis: {title: 'People'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Numbers'}};
var diffData = colChartDiff.computeDiff(oldData, newData);
colChartDiff.draw(diffData, options);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: You can't change the color of the old data.  I suggest making a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for this.

Comment: @asgallant its not true. At least not anymore. I can confirm that Bobs solution below works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set that in the diff object, e.g.,

```
var options = { ...
    diff: { 
        oldData: { opacity: 1, color: '#e6693e' }, 
        newData: { opacity: 1}
    }...
 }
```

Comment: I was trying to set color and opacity. It seems to work for pie and scatter plots however for histogram and column charts the 'opacity' does seem to do anything. I resorted to using the `dataOpacity` option located at `options.dataOpacity` to set the opacity for both `oldData` and `newData`

Comment: For what it is worth for historical reference, I also found a few interesting things in doing this just recently. For some reason the data sets must be named oldData and newData, you cannot choose any name you wish. If you do, you cannot use the diff option as it expects "oldData: and "newData". The color of newData must be set with colors in options and the coloring does not take place in the legend.

Comment: That's helpful, but I couldn't get the legend to reflect the new color that was changed.

Comment: Is there any option to change label

Comment: @KevinBrown - can you expand on your comment "The color of newData must be set with colors in options" - I have been trying to make this work